# Prevent recipients to change their email via Profile Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, profile

At my email footer, there is a link to the **Subscription Center** (`%%subscription_center_url%%`) where users can Unsubscribe. On the same page, if they switch the sidebar to Profile Center they can also change their email address. We have somehow managed to keep the link to Profile Center (`%%profile_center_url%%`) hidden in the email and Salesforce does not seem to complain.

But my customer would like to manage the changing of email address via their homepage and not the Marketing Cloud. This also causes overwriting issues since the back-system is not aware of the changes done within the Marketing Cloud.

How can I disable the option to change the email in the **Profile Center** (or possibly prevent them from landing on the Profile Center, to begin with)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by making the Email Address attribute readOnly in your Profile Center.

Go to Email Studio > Profile Center
then click on EmailAddress attribute and check the ReadOnly checkbox:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Rachid! Good to have a knowledgable source like you around.

Comment: Glad I can help !